# Como puedo mandar por post los datos de una tabla que se lleno con javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo la duda de como puedo sacar los Datos de una Tabla que se creo a partir de javascript, los datos se muestran correctamente e intente poner un input hidden para que esos datos de la tabla se guarden dentro anexo el codigo que hace que se visualicen  datos en una tabla justo después de presionar el boton Agregar

```
 $('#Agrega').click(function() {
        var Proye = document.getElementById("Proyectos").value;
        var Jefe = document.getElementById("veamo").value;
        var i = 1; //contador para asignar id al boton que borrara la fila
        var fila = '<tr id="row' + i + '"><td>' + Proye + '</td><td>' + Jefe + '</td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">Quitar</button></td></tr>'; //esto seria lo que contendria la fila

        i++;

        $('#Tabla tr:first').after(fila);
        $("#Agregar").text(""); //esta instruccion limpia el div adicionados para que no se vayan acumulando
        var nFilas = $("#Tabla tr").length;
        $("#Agregar").append(nFilas - 1);
        //le resto 1 para no contar la fila del header
        document.getElementById("veamo").value = "";
        document.getElementById("Proyectos").value = "";
        document.getElementById("Proyectos").focus();
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
        //cuando da click obtenemos el id del boton
        $('#row' + button_id + '').remove(); //borra la fila
        //limpia el para que vuelva a contar las filas de la tabla
        $("#Agregar").text("");
        var nFilas = $("#Tabla tr").length;
        $("#Agregar").append(nFilas - 1);


    });
});
```

Ese Codigo funciona Correctamente lo unico que quisiera saber es como mandar esos datos por POST Anexo el Modal donde se rellenan las tablas. Intente hacerlo con JQUERY pero solo encuentro informacion acerca de una sola celda.

```
<center>
    <div id="contact"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Nuevo_Depa">Añadir Empleados a Proyectos Especificos</button></div>
</center>
<div id="Nuevo_Depa" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3>Añadir </h3>
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
            </div>
            <form id="contactForm" name="contact" role="form" method="POST" action="../Control/InsertarProye.php">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <center><label for="inputName">Seleccionar un Proyecto</label></center>
                        <center>
                            <select for="inputName" name="Pro" id="Proyectos">
                                <option value="0">Seleccione un Proyecto:</option>
                                <?php
                                while ($Fila = mysqli_fetch_object($Listar)) {
                                    $NumerosPro = $Fila->NumPro;
                                    $NombresPro = $Fila->NomPro;
                                ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $NumerosPro. '-' . $NombresPro; ?> "><?php echo 'ID ' .$NumerosPro . '---' . $NombresPro; ?> </option>
                                <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                    <center>  <input type='text' name="Eliminar" id="Eliminar123"></center>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <center><label for="inputName">Seleccionar un Jefe de Proyecto</label></center>
                        <center>
                            <select for="inputName" name="Jef" id="veamo">
                                <option value="0">Seleccione un Empleado como Jefe de Proyecto</option>
                                <?php
                                while ($Fila2 = mysqli_fetch_object($Listar2)) {
                                    $Codigos = $Fila2->Codigo;
                                    $Nombres = $Fila2->Nombre;
                                ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $Codigos. '-' . $Nombres; ?> "><?php echo 'ID ' . $Codigos . '---' . $Nombres; ?> </option>
                                <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                            <center><label for="inputName">Quieres Elegir Alguno que se haya Postulado?</label></center>
                    </div>
                    <center> <button type="button" class="btn-sm btn btn-warning" id="Agrega">Agregar</button></center>

                    <div class="container">
                        <p>Elementos en las Tablas:
                        <div id="Agregar"></div>
                        </p>
                        <table id="Tabla" Name ="Jefe" class="table table-bordered table-hover ">
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID Proyecto</th>
                                <th>Jefe</th>
                                <th>Eliminar</th>


                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <center><label for="inputName">Seleccionar Empleados al Proyecto</label></center>
                        <center>
                            <select for="inputName" name="Emplea" id="ID_Emp">
                                <option value="0">Seleccione Empleados en el Proyecto</option>
                                <?php
                                while ($Fila3 = mysqli_fetch_object($Listar3)) {
                                    $Codigos = $Fila3->Codigo;
                                    $Nombres = $Fila3->Nombre;
                                ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $Codigos . '-' . $Nombres; ?> "><?php echo 'ID ' . $Codigos . '---' . $Nombres; ?> </option>
                                <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                            <center> <button type="button" class="btn-sm btn btn-warning " id="Incluye">Agregar</button></center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <p>Elementos en la Tabla:
                        <div id="Agregacion"></div>
                        </p>
                        <table id="Table" Name="Empleado" class="table table-bordered table-hover ">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Empleado</th>
                                <th>Eliminar</th>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="Entrega" id="submit">
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la `API Fetch` para hacer la peticion que necesitas.

**Por ejemplo:**

```
var url = 'https://example.com/profile';
var data = { username: 'example' };

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  body: JSON.stringify(data), // data can be `string` or {object}!
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .catch((error) => console.error('Error:', error))
  .then((response) => console.log('Success:', response));
```

Encuentra mas acerca de `API Fetch` [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)